# Open Android app using intent-filter not working

Tags: android

I have using the following code in the android manifest file,but its not open the application.

```
   <activity
        android:name="ActivityIntroScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="market" android:host="details" android:path="" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Where is the mistake...??

Comment: i think its becuse of more than one action specified...

Comment: Remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />` and have a try..

Comment: yes,it also not working

Comment: Can you pls try after commenting out the 2nd intent filter...Does that work???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to to single intent-filters for each scheme. have a look here: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's something in this block:

```
<intent-filter>
          <data android:scheme="market" android:host="details" android:path="" />
          <data android:scheme="http" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="play.google.com" android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=.*" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Without that block, it will work 100%. Just use process of elimination. :)